# How is the Android Gallery App handling Picasa media files?

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand how the Gallery App retrieves & handles Picasa media files.
I've compiled the Gallery2 sources from googlesource but the picasa albums are missing with that version.
Also after reviewing the code, I was not able to find the relevant sources.

Am I missing something?
Could it be that the published App has additional functionality, not included in the released sources?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation it turns out that the Gallery App which comes with Google's official version of Android is not the "Gallery2" App for which the sources are published.

To be more specific, the App name is "GalleryGoogle" and it includes lots of additional functionality such as handling Picasa sync.